# matplotlib fill between two sets of x,y points with regard to which set is on top

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have two sets of points which represent linear graphs (not necessarily functions)

```
a = [(1, 3), (3, 1), (7, 4), (6, 2), (13, 5)]
b = [(0, 0), (3, 3), (6, 1), (10, 4), (8, 2), (12, 1)]
```

I'm trying to color the areas between the two graphs s.t an area will be filled with one color when a is on top, and a different color when b is on top.

I have tried using plt.fill to create a polygon and color it but obviously it only works with one color.

```
plt.fill(
    np.append(a_x, b_x[::-1]),
    np.append(a_y, b_y[::-1]),
    color='green', alpha=0.1)
```

[image: only one color]

I have seen this done with plt.fill_between but only when there was only one x array, which is not the case here.

Comment: You need to interpolate onto a joint array which contains the points from both arrays.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest could you please elaborate? In my example i created a joint set of all the points to create a polygon. but it's not helpful since i cant distinguish which graph is on top at a given x value.

Comment: Can you comment on the necessity of the points being unordered? E.g. 6 coming after 7... this is quite unusual and complicates things. It also somehow does not allow to even say if something is on top or not.

Comment: It is necessary. These graphs show temperature over height. Sometimes the device drops in height and measures a different temperature than before. It is a known type of  meteorological data, which I try to implement using python's matplotlib library.

Comment: The examples found here https://matplotlib.org/2.0.2/examples/pylab_examples/fill_between_demo.html can get you part way there. The fact that both functions 'backtracks' at several points complicates things tough. Will it be like that in an actual case?

Comment: @mortysporty yes. As I said in my previous comment, this is a completely natural behavior in this kind of data

Comment: In that case, I'm not sure how to define "on top" in a mathematical sound way; so colorizing different parts would need to be done manually.